# What fraction of embryos fail to be born? And why that high?

Tags: human-biology, embryology, pregnancy

In the book Developmental Biology by Scott F. Gilbert and Michael J. Barresi, it says:

> Most human embryos die before being born. You survived.

So how come is that true???

And what percentage of pregnant women lose their unborn child(ren)?

Comment: How can we possibly know without knowing with certainty that a woman is pregnant? Many are lost only days after implantation.

Comment: What attempt have you made to answer this question on your own?

Comment: Is the fastet sperm always the best?

Comment: It's a tougher question than it looks; estimates vary pretty widely https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5443340/#__sec2title